# HTB qdisc child of another HTB qdisc drawbacks

Tags: qos, tc, htb

In the HTB documentation can be read:

> **Note:** HTB as child of another HTB is NOT the same as class under
>   another class within the same HTB. It is because when class in HTB can
>   send it will send as soon as hardware equipment can. So that delay of
>   underlimit class is limited only by equipment and not by ancestors. In
>   HTB under HTB case the outer HTB simulates new hardware equipment with
>   all consequences (**larger delay**)

**EDIT:**  My question is: the delay for having a qdisc children of another is large enough for not considering this approach over having only one qdisc?

The thing is that I **must** have enabled QoS because I want prioritize some traffic over other one, I'm just asking for the approach to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the question? Those two scenarios are completely different use cases. If you wouldn't want to have a larger delay for some of your packets, you hardly would turn to QoS, would you?

Comment: __@syneticon-dj:__ Hi! Thanks for your time. I updated the post on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are situations where you want delayed transmission - e.g. when simulating a slow link. In a simple case of prioritizing traffic, creating two or more HTB classes with different priorities and using filters to assign traffic to them would do. But nevertheless you should add the `stochastic fair queuing` qdisc as a child qdisc of your HTB classes to make sure that a single connection within a class does not starve the others. There are some examples at [lartc.org](http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.classful.html#AEN1072) on this topic - check them out.